# Scenario execution fails

Tags: daml

Guys this code is throwing up an error

```
daml 1.2

module PaidService where

template Service
  with
    provider : Party
    beneficiary : Party
    description : Text
    cost : Decimal
    currency : Text
  where
    signatory provider,beneficiary

    controller beneficiary can
      Transer   : ContractId Service
        with nextbeneficiary : Party
        do
          create this with beneficiary = nextbeneficiary


test_1 = scenario do
  beth <- getParty "beth"
  manish <- getParty "manish"
  harsha <- getParty "harsha"

  cid <- manish submit do
    create Service 
      with
        provider = manish
        beneficiary = manish
        description = "Yay"
        cost = 1000.00
        currency = "USD"
```

{
    "resource": "/home/Daml/learning/hackathon/daml/PaidService.daml",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "/home//Daml/learning/hackathon/daml/PaidService.daml:27:3: error:\n    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression\n      cid <- manish\n               submit\n               do create\n                    Service\n                      {provider = manish, beneficiary = manish, description = \"Yay\",\n                       cost = 1000.00, currency = \"USD\"}",
    "source": "typecheck",
    "startLineNumber": 27,
    "startColumn": 3,
    "endLineNumber": 34,
    "endColumn": 25
}

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in a `do`-block can not be of the form `a <- action`. Instead it must be an expression of type `f a` with `f = Scenario` in your example. The whole `do`-block will then also be of type `Scenario a`. There are two ways to fix your example.

1. Add another line at the end with `pure ()`. `pure` allows you to embed arbitrary values `a` into the context of a `do`-block (technically, it’s not limited to `do`-blocks but I won’t go into that here) so here it allows you to embed `()` into the `Scenario` context giving you a value of type `Scenario ()`.
2. Change

```
cid <- manish `submit` …
```

into

```
manish `submit` …
```

In your example that will result in the `do`-block having type `Scenario (ContractId Service)`.

The main difference between 1 and 2 is that in 1 `test_1` has type `Scenario ()` while in 2 `test_1` has type `Scenario (ContractId Service)`. For your example, that difference doesn’t matter as you don’t refer to `test_1` anywhere so both solutions are reasonable.

Comment: Wow that was an awesome explanation,Thanks!!!. I am a beginner in DAML and this solves a lot of my doubts. And I will remember to watch out for the return types.

Comment: Can you please tell  at which point can I add the () for this scenario to run properly?

Comment: Add a new line at the very end containing `pure ()` that is aligned with the previous line so `pure` and `cid <-` have to line up.

Comment: Works Perfectly . Thank You.